# LibGDX Sprites won't render

Tags: libgdx, sprite, render

I'm learning how to use sprite but I have ran into a problem. The sprites work fine when, say, there is one entity onscreen (the "Player") but once there are multiple entities on screen (the Player beings shooting, creating multiple bullet entities with sharing the same different sprite) the player disappears. In fact, when I added another sprite ("Box"), that entity too disappeared when the Player began shooting.

Here's how the sprites are set up. Please point out anything that may be causing the disappearances.

Each entity has a SpriteManager class with an ArrayList of Sprites (not the LibGDX one). You animate the sprite by calling a getCurrentSprite() and then rendering it. 
When initializing each entity you add Sprite classes to the EntityManager class so that you can switch between them if you're moving or standing still. Previously I chose which Sprites the entity uses from a static object defined elsewhere, but I thought that referencing the same object would cause trouble if, say, multiple bullets on screen are using the same object, so I had it create a completely new object each time. Once that happened, the bullets themselves began disappearing .5 seconds after being shot.

Edit: Shooting a single bullet won't make the player disappear, but shooting two bullets at once will. As soon as one bullet leaves the screen and is removed from the ArrayList (it no longer "exists"), the player pops back up. Basically, only one bullet may coexist with the player. Is it possible that any second or more bullets can "override" the player in some wierd way? I've checked; the player remains in the ArrayList and the function rendering its sprites is working too.

Comment: Can you show your Sprite class? Sounds like that's where the issue is. If this were the libgdx Sprite class, there would be no problem with referencing the same instance of a sprite from multiple different entities, although each of them would have to move it to the entity's location right before submitting it for drawing.

Comment: Without code we can't say you anything.